# get UIView's viewcontroller (iphone)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've done this to get the view:

```
[self.superview viewWithTag:10]
```

But how can I get that view's viewcontroller. Just like you can get the the viewcontroller's view I want to go the other way so I can send a message (call a method) to that viewcontroller. eg:

```
[[self.superview viewWithTag:10].viewController doSomething];
```

(obviously that not actual code but I want something like that)

Comment: have a look at protocols in objective c

Comment: Views shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340434/get-to-uiviewcontroller-from-uiview-on-iphone , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367348/how-to-get-a-uiviewcontroller-from-a-uiview-via-code

Answer (score 22):

You can use the `-nextResponder` method to do it:

```
[(YourUIViewController *)[[self.superview viewWithTag:10] nextResponder] doSomething];
```

According to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/nextResponder , "UIView implements this method by returning the UIViewController object that manages it (if it has one) or its superview (if it doesn’t)"

Comment: Is it really clean and safe to get the view's viewcontroller by calling this method ?

Comment: it's just [theView nextResponder];

Answer (score 12):

you can use

```
[yourUIView.window.rootViewController doSomething]
```

Comment: some further details answers on that ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/2596519/294884 may help someone