# presentModalViewController:animated not found

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

In the app I am trying to build, I am trying to use the **UIImageController** but am running into a bit of a problem.  I am not doing this in the **ViewController** class... Here's the code:

```
(IBAction) uploadBtn {   
ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
ipc.delegate = self;
ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];'
```

Its giving me a warning with the last line, saying:

```
Method'- presentModalViewController:animated' not found
```

I am sure that if I used the ViewController class this would work but is there anything I can do/import that will let me do this in just a UIView class?

Again the app builds, but when I try to click the button it crashes

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're crashing because only `UIViewController` has that method. You can only present one view controller off of another one.

Comment: I swear I thought I saw something that suggested a work around to it... Are you positive?? Or am I just going to have to move all this to the ViewController?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. Any workaround is going to consist of rebuilding a lot of code to *simulate* the view controller hierarchy. It's not worth fighting the system.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [get UIView's viewcontroller (iphone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025370/get-uiviews-viewcontroller-iphone). I think you should rethink your design if you need to access view controller from a UIView.

Answer (score 0):

You could present it from the view's parent view controller:

```
[[ipc parentViewController] presentModalViewController:yourController animated:yourBool];
```